# Need to solve this

Tags: c#

```
public class SelectedItems
{
    public Item item;
    public int quantity;
    public double subtotal = 0.0;

}

public class Item
{
    public int itemcode;
    public string itemname;
    public double unitprice = 0.0;
}

/* These are my classes */


class Program
{
    public static ArrayList details = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList purchased = new ArrayList();


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Item i1 = new Item();
        i1.itemcode = 1111;
        i1.itemname = "Pants";
        i1.unitprice = 950.00;

        Item i2 = new Item();
        i2.itemcode = 2222;
        i2.itemname = "Dress";
        i2.unitprice = 850.00;

        Item i3 = new Item();
        i3.itemcode = 3333;
        i3.itemname = "Blouse";
        i3.unitprice = 650.00;

        Item i4 = new Item();
        i4.itemcode = 4444;
        i4.itemname = "Shirt";
        i4.unitprice = 1500.00;

        Item i5 = new Item();
        i5.itemcode = 5555;
        i5.itemname = "Belt";
        i5.unitprice = 1200.00; 


        details.Add(i1);
        details.Add(i2);
        details.Add(i3);
        details.Add(i4);
       // details.Add(i5);

       details.Add(new Item { itemcode = 5555, itemname = "Belt", unitprice = 1200.00 });

        /*Console.WriteLine("Enter the code :");
        searchItem(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.ReadLine();*/

      Console.Write("Number Of Different Items:");
      int count = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

     while (count > 0)
     {  
        SelectedItems stm = new SelectedItems();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the code :");
        Item im = searchItem(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

        if (stm.item == null)

            Console.WriteLine("no item");

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the quantity :");
            stm.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
            stm.subtotal = stm.item.unitprice * (Convert.ToDouble(stm.quantity));

            purchased.Add(stm);
        } 
        count--;
     }
     //printBill();
    }
    public static Item searchItem(int code)
    {
        foreach (Item i in details)
        {
            if (code == i.itemcode)
            {
                return i;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} : {2}", i.itemcode, i.itemname, i.unitprice);
            }
        }
         return null;
    }
```

This always returns no item.Can I get clear cut in this? I posted this earlier and was able to get it correct , now it gives back a headache

Comment: You appear to be abusing classes! Maybe don’t. Also, `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`, please, and `PascalCase` for properties.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning your search item into an object of your item class, but doing nothing with it. You then do your comparing on your newly created SelectItem which is Null at the time since you have not added your item to it. try changing.

```
while (count > 0)
 {  
    SelectedItems stm = new SelectedItems();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the code :");
    Item im = searchItem(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())); //You are returning an item here and doing nothing
                                                               //with it. this is the only time you reference it
    if (stm.item == null)    //You are checking an empty(null) instance of your selectedItems class that you
                             // just created.
        Console.WriteLine("no item");

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the quantity :");
        stm.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
        stm.subtotal = stm.item.unitprice * (Convert.ToDouble(stm.quantity));

        purchased.Add(stm);
    } 
    count--;
 }
```

to

```
while (count > 0)
 {  
    SelectedItems stm = new SelectedItems();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the code :");
    Item im = searchItem(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

    if (im == null)   //Check if searchItem returned an object.

        Console.WriteLine("no item");

    else
    {
        stm.Item = im;  // Added item to your selected items
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the quantity :");
        stm.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
        stm.subtotal = stm.item.unitprice * (Convert.ToDouble(stm.quantity));

        purchased.Add(stm);
    } 
    count--;
 }
```

Comment: Now i get a FormatException in  `Item im = searchItem(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));` when i insert **2** for count and this occurs in 2nd count...

Comment: Since you accepted my answer I am supposing you figured it out. The problem lies in the fact that you are using `Console.Read` instead of `Console.ReadLine` to get your quantity that is leaving CRLF in the buffer which is causing your Format Exception.

Comment: It worked perfectly..great but i can't figure it out how that caused the exception neither your above explanation so can i get some link or anywy you could help me to get it into my head..it would be so helpful

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx reads next character http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx reads the next line. You were leaving extra characters in the keyboard buffer most probably the Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
if (stm.item == null)

Console.WriteLine("no item");
```

To

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stm.item))

    Console.WriteLine("no item");
```

Comment: That’ll make it show “no item” ≥ as often, whereas the problem is apparently that it’s shown too much.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the top of the loop to this:

```
        SelectedItems stm = new SelectedItems();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the code :");
        stm.item = searchItem(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
```

It doesn't look like you're assigning the stm.item property.

Answer (score 0):

> ArrayList belongs to the days that C# didn't have generics. It's
>   deprecated in favor of List. You shouldn't use ArrayList in new
>   code that targets .NET >= 2.0

Try using

```
public static IList<Item> details = new List<Item>();
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are writing it to console which never get executed because of return statement just above it.

Change it as:

```
if (code == i.itemcode)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} : {2}", i.itemcode, i.itemname, i.unitprice);
    return i;
}
```

and assign your result to object you are checking for null:

```
Item stm = new Item ();
Console.WriteLine("Enter the code :");
stm= searchItem(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

if (stm == null){//other code}
```

Comment: but there is an class called stm(Selected Items) and i have called the ITem class in it....

Comment: but you assigned your search result to `Item im = searchItem(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));` and checking stm for null

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if (stm.item == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("no item");
}
```

to

```
if (im == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("no item");
}
```

It Works!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning any value to the property **stm.item**. So that it will be always null and **if (stm.item == null)** will always be true.

I don't know why you are using **if (stm.item == null)** there, but you have to do some thing like shown below.

```
stm.item = "Test";
if (stm.item == null)
    Console.WriteLine("no item");
```

There is some issue in **searchItem** function as well

No statement execute after return statement.

```
return i;
Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} : {2}", i.itemcode, i.itemname, i.unitprice);
```